# How to prevent SAPUI5 from log output in console?

Tags: sapui5

I developed a Fiori application with SAPUI5 inside of the WEBIde. When I open console of the browser I see some log inside of the console that are generated automatically with SAPUI5.

[image]

How can I prevent SAPUI5 from generating unwanted logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [jQuery.sap.log.setLevel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.html#.setLevel) in your Component initialization.  Valid parameter values include:

- [jQuery.sap.log.Level.ERROR (Error level.)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.Level.html#.ERROR)
- [jQuery.sap.log.Level.NONE (Do not log anything).](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.Level.html#.NONE)

However, I'm not sure if any of the messages in your screen shot get generated prior to the component being initialized.

Edit: If your app isn't launched from Fiori Launchpad, you could try setting the log level in your bootstrap code - i.e. in `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit()`.

Comment: I tested your solution in both places. but unfortunately none of the work. Actually the outputs come before `compunent.js` initialization and even before `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit()`

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh Ok, sorry then I'd expect it might not be possible and I'm out of ideas unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This was identified as a bug ([OpenUI5 issue #2692](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2692)) which got fixed with the release of UI5 version 1.72.0. The only UI5 produced log left from the console is "Device API logging initialized" from the `sap/ui/Device`<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/5749710ec2b9344adceab01b088f5c94138799e3/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/Device.js#L109)</sup> which cannot be controlled by `sap/base/Log` yet.

> Since we cannot use the logging from jquery.sap.global.js, we need to come up with a separate solution for the device API.

Other issue messages are from the browser, one of which can be resolved by [removing sync XHRs from the application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461248/5846045).

Since UI5 1.72 and with asynchronous loading, the console is much cleaner now:

[image: UI5 console log since 1.72.0]
<sup>From: https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/16J1TFICxbqETCzaxuZ0/?sap-ui-xx-componentPreload=off</sup>