# How to avoid "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread" warning in UI5?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I'm staring my UI5 with the following bootstrapping in `index.js`:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/Shell",
    "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
], (Core, Shell, ComponentContainer) => {
    "use strict";

    new Shell("", {
        app: new ComponentContainer("", {
            height: "100%",
            name: "webapp"
        }),
        appWidthLimited: false
    }).placeAt("content");
});
```

According to the [UI5 documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html):

> *Static dependencies are loaded in the dependency declaration array of the `sap.ui.define` call. **These dependencies are always loaded in advance** before executing the defined module*.

Do I understand it correctly that in such case the modules will be always loaded in a synchronous way and there is no real way to avoid the *«Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread»* warning?

Can I, perhaps, just wrap `new sap.m.Shell(sId?, mSettings?)` with `async`/`await`?

### Update #1:

I've checked the loading with `?sap-ui-xx-nosync=warn` and got the following results:

[image]

For some reason `i18n/i18n_en.properties` is loaded synchronously. The only place where I'm accessing the `i18n` is:

```js
const oBundle = myI18nModel.getResourceBundle();
```

But following the documentation, I could not grasp why `myI18nModel.getResourceBundle()` leads to the synchronous loading.

### Update #2:

After a deep exploration of [no sync XHR](https://embed.plnkr.co/7txzTsNwOBDbyi87) sample, I found out the reason for the `sync XHR` warning. That was `"description": "{{appDescription}}"` and `"title": "{{appTitle}}"` in `manifest.json` which is explicitly noted:

```json
"title": "Here the i18n bundles can't be loaded with 'async: true' yet!",
"description": "Same here. Hence, no 'i18n' in this 'sap.app' section!"
```

After replacing it with a static values the warning is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

Historically, UI5 1.x had been offering APIs based on [synchronous XHRs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request). Legacy applications or outdated documentation topics might still refer to:

- APIs that have the **asynchronous option disabled by default** such as the `sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer`, `sap.ui.core.Core#loadLibrary`, etc..
- APIs that have **no async option** at all such as `sap.ui.controller`, `sap.ui.component`, `sap.ui.*fragment`, `sap.ui.*view`, `jQuery.sap.*`, `sap.ui.requireSync`, `oCore.createComponent`, `sap.ushell.Container.getService`, etc.. Replacement for them are documented in the API reference.

## Resolution

In order to get rid of sync XHRs in UI5:

1. Do **not** use deprecated APIs such as those mentioned above. Deprecated APIs will be removed in the next major UI5 version (2.x). [UI5 linter](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-linter) might help to detect deprecated APIs in your project.
2. Follow the documented guidelines:

   - [Use Asynchronous Loading](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/676b636446c94eada183b1218a824717)
   - [Performance Checklist](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/9c6400eb7dc145b78e94a81e6e390780)
   - [Is Your Application Ready for Asynchronous Loading?](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01)

   Particularly when bootstrapping, use the `data-sap-ui-async="true"` option, and, if the app has a `Component.js`, [**use the declarative `sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport` module in `data-sap-ui-oninit`**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/82a0fcecc3cb427c91469bc537ebdddf) instead of instantiating `sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer` manually. For example:

   ```html
   <head>
     <!-- ... -->
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
       data-sap-ui-async="true"
       data-sap-ui-onInit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
       data-sap-ui-resourceRoots='{ "my.demo": "./" }'
       data-...="..."
     ></script>
   </head>
   <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
     <div data-sap-ui-component
       data-id="rootComponentContainer"
       data-name="my.demo"
       data-settings='{ "id": "myRootComponent" }'
       data-...="..."
     ></div>
   </body>
   ```

   This automatically creates a `ComponentContainer`, puts it in the DOM, and loads the corresponding `Component.js` and `manifest.json` **asynchronously** altogether while avoiding inline script or a separate bootstrap script at the same time.

   In the application's `Component.js` definition, additionally, implement the `"sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"` marker interface to allow creating the component's content fully asynchronously (in addition to stricter error handling).

   ```js
   // In Component.js
   return UIComponent.extend("my.demo.Component", {
     metadata: {
       interfaces: [ "sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation" ],
       manifest: "json",
     },
     // ...
   });
   ```

3. **For UI5 1.x**: run the app with the [`xx-nosync` bootstrap option](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b474a712ca364d40a1b0a804baf2d734). For example, in the URL:

   ```
   https://<host>/my/awesome/app/?sap-ui-xx-nosync=warn
   ```

   UI5 will then log **"loading … with sync XHR"** or **"[nosync] loading module '…'"** in the browser console for each file fetched synchronously (Ignore other [nosync] messages). For example:

   - Standalone apps using `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` with older UI5 versions might require `sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs` synchronously (C.f. [issue #3134](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3134)). In that case, add the module to the `sap-ui-modules` bootstrap config:

     ```html
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
       data-sap-ui-async="true"
       data-sap-ui-onInit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
       data-sap-ui-modules="sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs"
       ...
     ></script>
     ```

     In an FLP scenario, the `datajs` module should be already preloaded by the launchpad.
   - If a [`ResourceModel`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel#constructor) is created manually in JS, make sure to enable the `async` flag there:

     ```js
     const i18nModel = new ResourceModel({ // sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel
       bundleName: "demo.i18n.i18n",
       supportedLocales: [""],
       fallbackLocale: "",
       async: true, // <--
     });
     const resourceBundle = await i18nModel.getResourceBundle();
     this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
     resourceBundle.getText("...", [/*...*/]); // sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle
     ```

   Check the API reference of the reported APIs. Most of the times, they're either deprecated or they come with an `async` flag set to `false` by default.
4. When requesting UI5 theming parameters via [`sap.ui.core.theming.Parameters.get`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.theming.Parameters#methods/Summary), use the **asynchronous variant** as mentioned in the API description. If there are standard UI5 controls requesting theming parameters too early - causing a sync XHR - create an issue in OpenUI5 GitHub.

See also other [best practices for UI5 developers](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/28fcd55b04654977b63dacbee0552712).
If the app is supposed to start from SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP), follow [How to make UI5 content compatible with the FLP setting "Asynchronous Module Loading" and CSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959323/5846045)

## Known issues

There are, however, still some APIs left which have no asynchronous replacements *yet* such as:

- [OpenUI5 issue #2345](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2345): CLDR being fetched with sync XHR when instantiating `sap/ui/core/LocaleData` (Used in e.g. Calendar or DatePicker).
- <del>[OpenUI5 issue #3331](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3331#issuecomment-914191591)</del>: i18n Handlebar-like `"{{...}}"`-syntax in `manifest.json` resulting in sync XHRs. (Should not be an issue if the `*.properties` files are included in the generated application bundle `Component-preload.js`). → ✅ Fixed with [`ad5cf65`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ad5cf65cae48dcaac64f9bd83e5430e0d3ae2023).
- <del>[OpenUI5 issue #3134](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3134)</del>: `v2.ODataModel` requiring `datajs.js` synchronously if created with `preload: true` in `manifest.json`. → ✅ Fixed with [`337b176`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/337b1768cff287cf22c3fbfe4458afd66795c894).

---

To answer the question: `sap.ui.define` and `sap.ui.require` do load dependencies asynchronously **if** the `data-sap-ui-async` config is set to `true` which [can replace `data-sap-ui-preload="async"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804167/5846045). Also, make sure to [add dependent libs to the `manifest.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835493/5846045) in order to prevent a major performance bottleneck.

Wrapping a synchronous content request with async-await or Promise won't help. Better look for asynchronous alternatives. For example, the [`ComponentContainer`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer#constructor) has an `async` flag in the constructor settings which, if enabled, fetches the `Component.js` and `manifest.json` files asynchronously:

```js
new ComponentContainer({ // required from "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
  height: "100%",
  name: "my.demo",
  async: true, // or
  manifest: true, // sets the `async` option automatically to true
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` warning in the console might be from leftovers from the actual core. I know the launchpad has some issues in this regard. If you time it or have a closer look at your network tab / sources tab you'll find the message is displayed before your own code is loaded.

Somewhere in a file like `sap.jquery.js` or something along those lines you'll find `XMLHtppRequests` with the `sync` flag set. I've had conversations with the UI5 team about it and removing it is on the radar but no timelines are provided.

To answer your question more directly, the `require` parts are meant to be asynchronous. It's an idea taken from [require js](https://requirejs.org/) which is at least 10 years old by now.

// edit

`async`/`await` is not going to do anything since none of that is promise based. Doing `sap.m.Shell` is just assuming that the window object has the `sap.m` library attached to it before your controller loads, which you can make sure to preload through your manifest for instance.